# Best way to present a 5-star rating system

Tags: ratings

On our corporate intranet website, we have a section where we publish articles and presentations and such, and there's a 5-star system to rate the items.

As expected, when the article page is open, the stars on the top show its current rating, and if the user clicks on the stars, his rating is saved and shown instead.

My question is: is there some way to show the average article rating even *after* the user has cast his vote? Or it isn't necessary after all? Because I always have the feeling that something is missing when that information is not there, but it may be just me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe a simple toggle pattern like this appears when the user creates a rating?

[image: ratings]

Comment: @Fabio - Or, if you want to display a decimal place in the average, replace the suggested "Average Rating" clickable area with a label: "Average Rating: 4.2"