# How to present a multi-facet 5-star rating system?

Tags: mobile, ratings, ease-of-use

I want to design a multi-facet 5 star rating system on mobile devices, for the intent of attribute analytics. In layman's terms, I want to be able to present the user with a list of characteristics for an object, and have then have them rate the objects based on each of the characteristics (1-5 stars). For example, I could make the object an apple, and then have users rate the Apple 1-5 stars on it's Texture, Taste, Color, Feel, etc. This way, I can manage a group of objects and I will be able to analyze where each object succeeds and fails.

The trick to this, is that the rating system will be on mobile devices. How can I present a multi-facet rating system on such a small screen so that it's easy to use, and not too small?

This question is different from [Best way to present a 5-star rating system](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/61147/best-way-to-present-a-5-star-rating-system) in that I know how I plan on presenting the rating system, I just need to find a way to present a lot of these rating systems on a relatively small screen area.

Comment: Are you more concerned with comfortably displaying as many objects to rate as possible on a mobile screen or the actual space of the single object's ratings?

Comment: I'm interested in what would be better for a user? Allocating a page to each rating might be easier to understand, but running through multiple objects with multiple characteristics would require a bunch of pages and might be fatiguing to the user. On the other hand, displaying all the ratings on a single page might solve the fatigue issue, but also might be overwhelming and hard to use...

Comment: Please consider marking your question answered. Should you need more information, please feel free to edit your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am a strong supporter of concentrating on a **single object at a time when rating**. This makes it less overwhelming for the user.

I think some kind of swipeable card system would make this rating system more intuitive and maximizes the space you have for each object's variable number of rating systems:

[image]

**First mockup**: Initial state. First object to be rated.

**Second**: Completed object that's fully rated.

**Third**: Transitioning to the next object to rate as the user swipes.

**Fourth**: The next object. So on and so forth..

Would something like this work for your requirements?

Comment: the *swiping card* idea is really nice, +1

Comment: Adrienne Tacke proposed a very effective solution [thumbsup!]. This is what I would use myself, maybe with a slight change: moving only the "product" (while keeping the attribute list fixed, simply changing values for each product) instead of moving the entire screen content as a card. Ofc, this works only if the attribute list is consistent for all products.

Comment: Thank you! I really like your suggestion of swiping just the product as well and support that change as long as the attribute list is the same among all products.